# Is my permanent address proofs valid for passport application?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, paperwork

I am an Indian citizen who wants to apply for a passport. In India, an "address proof" is a document which proves where you live and is required for passport applications, among other things.

For the last three years I have been working in a city while living in a rented home. This is my **present address**. But there is also a home owned by my family, which I could also potentially use. I have submitted both the rented home and the family home in the application.

My father works in the government, and lives in a home provided by the government. I don't want to use that address proof, as he will retire in a few months and thus relocate from that home.

For my present address (the rented home) I believe I have these types of proofs:

1. [Aadhar card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aadhaar)
2. Bank passbook with photo
3. [Voter ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter_ID_(India))

But for my family home (the home owned by my family) all the documents are in the names of family members. The only thing in my own name is #4, which I'm not sure about.

I have the following for the family home:

1. Water bill  (in the name of my paternal grandfather.)
2. Electricity bill (in the name of my paternal grandfather.)
3. Gas Connection (in the name of paternal uncle.)
4. A piece of land attached to my house registered in my name. (Not sure if this is applicable for address proof.)
5. Telephone bill (in the name of paternal uncle.)

Which of these documents (if any) will be useful for a passport application?

Comment: Why would you need proof of your address for your family home, when you don't actually live there?

Comment: @DJClayworth For the purposes of the passport, he can list it as his home. He only needs one adress proof, but he may fear that he doesn't *have* a proper one for the rented home.

Comment: @Fiksdal : I have proper for rented home, but not for the family home

Comment: @trex Then why don't you just use the one from the rented home?

Comment: @Fiksdal: In this case I would say, I am not sure, whether I need to furnish both the addresses or only one is enough.

Comment: @trex Why would you need to document the family home? You don't live there and you're not the formal owner.

Comment: @Fiksdal   Indian passport application contains fields for both present and permanent addresses (if any). As I have both the addresses. since I am trying to collect permanent address documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indian passport application requires to give address proof of all the places you have lived in past one year.

Since you have been living in your rented place for last three years, so it is absolutely valid to use it as your address proof. You don't have to provide any other place as proof of address. You can use Aadhar card and Voter Id as your address proof.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing here is to simply ask the people in charge of issuing passports at the Collectors Office. Tell them about whatever documents you have, and ask them if any of them will do. Your situation would likely be a common one, and the official has probably dealt with it before. Just ask the officials about your documents.

In the case that none of your documents are applicable, your last resort would be to get a phone connection or something in your own name. You may be able to find one without a monthly fee where you just pay for usage.

Comment: I believe, lots of indians might have similar situation. So I will consider your answer(suggestion) as a last option.

Comment: @trex Yes, I certainly hope you get an answer from someone more experienced. It may save you the time of having to ask the officials. But after all, you'll have to get in touch with the officials in the end anyway.

Comment: Yes you're right (y)

Comment: And it has now happened :)

Comment: Yes ;). But actually I should accept your answer (aka efforts). I had confirmed with Passport officials and they mentioned exactly as `boroxun`' s answer. So I considered his answer as it was more accurate. 
Don't mind :)

Comment: @trex Of course not. As a matter of fact, I would have protested if you *had* accepted my answer instead of the other one.